# MediaPlayer throwing IllegalStateException when calling onStop()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an `AlertDialog`, which stops playing a sound when I have clicked, but on some devices it appears that calling `onStop()` throws an `IllegalStateException`, but why?

If the dialog is up, that means the sound is playing, so it should be a case where the audio is not playing.

I surrounded it with a try catch for now, but what would cause this?

```
alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                try{
                mp.stop(); //error
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Nitif Activity", e.toString());
                }
                v.cancel();

                popupMessage();                 
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you might be nulling your instance before executing these lines.
When I got this error I check for null first.

```
if (mp != null) {
    try {
        mp.stop(); //error
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Nitif Activity", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer when it doesn't even address the correct kind of Exception... @tyczj

Comment: @Deepak-question and answer are same why?

Comment: `if(mp != null)` was added it seems

Answer (score 31):

Checking `mp != null` prevents a `NullPointerException` but the `IllegalStateException` can't be caused by that.

The reason you get that error is that the player is in a state where it can't `stop()`. If you have a look at the state-diagram at the top of the [MediaPlayer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) you can see that stop can only be called after the player is in the `Prepared` state. The next possibility is that you have already called `release()` or `reset()` which will also result in that error.

You can call `stop()` only in `Prepared`, `Started`, `Paused`, `PlaybackComplete` or `Stopped` state. All other states produce that error.

So you either do `prepareAsync()` and the user hits the button before your player is prepared or you have code that releases or resets the player before you hit the button.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `mp` isn't initialized, [Dev Resource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop%28%29);

Try adding:

```
if(mp != null)
```

Comment: that dont make sens that it wouldnt be initialized because it gets initialized right before it plays. Not saying you are wrong just saying that it wouldnt make sense that its not

Comment: @Sam- I have a question when device is silent mode but player already started then I call  if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
            player.release();
            player=null;
        } in this case got Illegal Exception please look why it is happening

Comment: Checking for null does not guarantee that the MediaPlayer isn't in an illegal state.

Answer (score 0):

Checking mp!=null prevents when it is null, but your mediaplayer never goes null.
just add mp=null; where you are doing mp.stop();